# Move (translated+transition) panoramic photo depending mouse position

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following situation: I have a centered panoramic photo (the right and left parts of the picture not visible yet on the screen).

I would like that, depending on the mouse position (related to the middle X of the picture) the pictures:

-> moves (as if in a virtual tour) to the left (if the mouse is on the right part of the photo);

-> moves to the right (if the mouse is on the left part of the picture);

-> and comes back to the initial centered position (when the mouse is outside the pictures).

This is how I tried (movement in only one direction; but I want/need two directions):

```
<head>
 <style type="text/css">
  #smartdemo3 {
     width: 75%;
     overflow: hidden;
  }

  #smartdemo3 img:hover {
     transform: translate3d(-200px, 0px, 0px);
     transition: transform 5s linear;
  }

  #smartdemo3 img {
     transition: 4s all ease-in-out;
  }
 </style>
</head>

<body>
 <div id="smartdemo3">
  <img src="../images/Panint1.jpg" />
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

How could I do that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

Fiddle demo: https://jsfiddle.net/os0moz5j/1/

HTML

```
<div class="panorama default">
  <img src="https://unsplash.it/2500/500?image=914">
</div>
```

CSS

```
.panorama{ width:400px; height:200px; margin:100px; overflow:hidden; position:relative; }
.panorama img{ height:200px; width:auto; position:absolute; left:0;  }

.panorama.default img{ left:50%; transform:translateX(-50%); transition:all .2s ease; }
```

JS

```
$('.panorama').on('mousemove',function(e){
    mousePos = e.pageX - $(this).offset().left;
    eleWidth = $(this).outerWidth();
    imgWidth = $(this).find('img').outerWidth();
    relativeMousePos = mousePos / eleWidth;
    imgPos = (imgWidth - eleWidth) * relativeMousePos;
    $(this).find('img').css('transform','translateX(-'+imgPos+'px)');
});

$('.panorama').on('mouseenter',function(){
    $(this).removeClass('default');
}).on('mouseleave',function(){
    $(this).addClass('default');
    $(this).find('img').css('transform','');
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.

I would like though, that the pictures moves itself when the mouse is on either side of the picture. If I point the mouse on the right side (the mouse is still, not moving) the picture moves to the left and vice versa.

Also, if I want the picture to move slower is it enough to modify the value .2s from transition in panorama.default.img?

Also, to have a perfectly centered pictures, what do I need to modify?

Million thanks for your help.